# Methods for writing Parquet files using Python?

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet, snappy

I'm having trouble finding a library that allows Parquet files to be written using Python. Bonus points if I can use Snappy or a similar compression mechanism in conjunction with it.

Thus far the only method I have found is using Spark with the `pyspark.sql.DataFrame` Parquet support.

I have some scripts that need to write Parquet files that are not Spark jobs. Is there any approach to writing Parquet files in Python that doesn't involve `pyspark.sql`?

Comment: it seems that the Parquet format has thirft definition files can't you use this to access it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Update (March 2017):** There are currently **2** libraries capable of *writing* Parquet files:

1. [fastparquet](https://github.com/dask/fastparquet)
2. [pyarrow](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/python-parquet-update/)

Both of them are still under heavy development it seems and they come with a number of disclaimers (no support for nested data e.g.), so you will have to check whether they support everything you need.

OLD ANSWER:

**As of 2.2016 there seems to be NO python-only library capable of *writing* Parquet files.**

If you only need to *read* Parquet files there is [python-parquet](https://github.com/jcrobak/parquet-python).

As a workaround you will have to rely on some other process like e.g. `pyspark.sql` (which uses Py4J and runs on the JVM and can thus not be used directly from your average CPython program).

Comment: If you need to be able to append data to existing files, like writing multiple dfs in batches, fastparquet does the trick. I could not find a single mention of append in pyarrow and seems the code is not ready for it (March 2017).

Answer (score 9):

[fastparquet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fastparquet) does have write support, here is a snippet to write data to a file

```
from fastparquet import write
write('outfile.parq', df)
```

Answer (score 9):

## Simple method to write pandas dataframe to parquet.

Assuming, `df` is the pandas dataframe. We need to import the following libraries.

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
```

First, write the dataframe `df` into a `pyarrow` table.

```
# Convert DataFrame to Apache Arrow Table
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df_image_0)
```

Second, write the `table` into `parquet` file say `file_name.parquet`

```
# Parquet with Brotli compression
pq.write_table(table, 'file_name.parquet')
```

## NOTE: parquet files can be further compressed while writing. Following are the popular compression formats.

- Snappy ( default, requires no argument)
- Gzip
- Brotli

Parquet with Snappy compression

```
 pq.write_table(table, 'file_name.parquet')
```

Parquet with GZIP compression

```
pq.write_table(table, 'file_name.parquet', compression='GZIP')
```

Parquet with Brotli compression

```
pq.write_table(table, 'file_name.parquet', compression='BROTLI')
```

#### Comparative comparison achieved with different formats of parquet

[image]

Reference:
https://tech.jda.com/efficient-dataframe-storage-with-apache-parquet/

Comment: Note that compression depends on the content. Brotli is especially efficient in code/English, as it was tuned from HTML code samples for a fixed dictionary.

Answer (score 6):

I've written a comprehensive guide to Python and Parquet with an emphasis on taking advantage of Parquet's three primary optimizations: *columnar storage*, *columnar compression* and *data partitioning*. There is a fourth optimization that isn't covered yet, row groups, but they aren't commonly used. The ways of working with Parquet in Python are pandas, PyArrow, fastparquet, PySpark, Dask and AWS Data Wrangler.

Check out the post here: [Python and Parquet Performance In Pandas, PyArrow, fastparquet, AWS Data Wrangler, PySpark and Dask](https://blog.datasyndrome.com/python-and-parquet-performance-e71da65269ce)

Answer (score 5):

using `fastparquet` you can write a pandas `df` to parquet either with`snappy` or `gzip` compression as follows:

make sure you have installed the following:

```
$ conda install python-snappy
$ conda install fastparquet
```

do imports

```
import pandas as pd 
import snappy
import fastparquet
```

assume you have the following pandas `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
```

send `df` to parquet with `snappy` compression

```
df.to_parquet('df.snap.parquet',compression='snappy')
```

send `df` to parquet with `gzip` compression

```
df.to_parquet('df.gzip.parquet',compression='gzip')
```

check:

read parquet back into pandas `df`

```
pd.read_parquet('df.snap.parquet')
```

or

```
pd.read_parquet('df.gzip.parquet')
```

output:

```
   col1 col2
0   1    3
1   2    4
```

Answer (score 2):

`pyspark` seems to be the best alternative right now for writing out parquet with python. It may seem like using a sword in place of needle, but thats how it is at the moment.

- It supports most compression types like lzo, snappy. Zstd support should come into it soon.
- Has complete schema support (nested, structs, etc)

Simply do, `pip install pyspark` and you are good to go.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-parquet.html

Answer (score 1):

Two more Python libraries for fast CSV => parquet transformations:

1. DuckDB https://duckdb.org
2. Polars https://github.com/pola-rs/polars

May not have all the bells and whistles of fastparquet but are really fast and easy to master.

**Edit**
Polars can write parquet using Arrows, which supports new parquet versions and options:
https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.write_table.html