# Convert xlsx to parquet

Tags: python, excel, xlsx, parquet, apache-nifi

Is it possible to convert a xlsx excel file in parquet without converting in csv ? 
The thing is that i have many excel files with each many sheets and i don't want to convert each sheet in csv and then in parquet so i wonder if there is a way to convert directly excel to parquet ? Or maybe, is there a way to do it with nifi ? 
I wanted to do it this way using a python script

```
def csv_from_excel():

wb = xlrd.open_workbook('your_workbook.xls')
sh = wb.sheet_names()
for i in sh:
    sh = wb.sheet_by_name(i)
    your_csv_file = open('your_csv_file.csv', 'wb')
    wr = csv.writer(your_csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

    for rownum in xrange(sh.nrows):
        wr.writerow(sh.row_values(rownum))

    your_csv_file.close()
`
```

Comment: Very related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32940416/methods-for-writing-parquet-files-using-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a Nifi perspective, the two interesting questions here are:

1. Can Nifi pick up this Excel?

This should not be too difficult when leveraging the [XLSX processor](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-poi-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.poi.ConvertExcelToCSVProcessor/), but if your situation is a bit more complex, [this elaborate HCC article](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/155221/use-nifi-to-process-excel-spreadsheets-in-automate-1.html) might be helpful.

2. Can Nifi write to Parquet?

This part is easy, with the [PutParquet processor](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-parquet-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.parquet.PutParquet/index.html), Nifi can directly write to Parquet.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following code and install all required libraries

```html
import os
import fnmatch
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import openpyxl

path = './'
pattern = 'mydataset.xlsx'
all_files = os.listdir(path)

for name in all_files:
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, pattern):
        df = pd.read_excel(name)
        table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
        pq.write_table(table, name + '.parquet')
```

Comment: I managed to use this